# How to add event and event description via popover in full calendar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, popover

I have used full calendar for displaying events and holidays. The events are generated from a json file. How to enter the events in the frontend (i.e) If the user click on a particular date , it should show a empty popover to enter the title and description of the event. How to achieve this ?

fiddle link is in the comment ....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7gwz5/1/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the description is the content of the event, then you can change this line:

```
content: event.msg
```

to

```
content: event.title
```

**EDIT after reading the below comments:**

I just added this closure in your window.load closure.
This is working in Firefox, but in Chrome is half-functional (works just the first line of code).
In Firefox, you can track the edited events by the user through its parents and save it in an associative array of dates and text.

```
 $(document).on('dblclick', '.popover-title, .popover-content', function(){
         $(this).html('&nbsp;');
         $(this).attr('contentEditable',true);
    });
```

Comment: Well I know that. I want to give permission to the client to add event and event description in the particular date. For Example If I click the some date in the calendar it should show popover with empty content to add events .

Comment: Do you want to save the input values from user, or just have the values for the current browser session?

Comment: Yes I want to save the input values from a user

Comment: Understood the question ??

Comment: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/select_callback/. This is a select call back on click of day cell. Initiate a dialog box at this call back event.

Comment: @RohithNair when i click a particular date it shows popup but it doesn't allows to edit either or to save.

Comment: I have not done any coding for that in the fiddle, as I said its a starting point. Put a text box, text area in the dialog box populate the dialog box with the data you require and on click of button , call your server code, which inserts to DB or necessary code to render it client side